# insert and delete rows form a table

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I created a database called orthomcl

```
CREATE DATABASE orthomcl;
CREATE USER 'orthomcl'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON orthomcl.* TO 'orthomcl'@'localhost';
SELECT * FROM mysql.db WHERE Db = 'orthomcl'\G;
```

I then inserted a table called similarSequences to the database orthomcl

to check if I have duplicate entries in the table I used the following command

```
USE orthomcl;

select * from similarSequences group by query_id,subject_id having count(*)>1;
```

this command then returned the following result:

```
 134674 rows in set (5 min 20.81 sec)
```

Then I created a new table that will have only distinct rows.

```
create table holdup as select distinct * from similarSequences;
```

And this resulted in

```
 mysql> create table holdup as select distinct * from similarSequences;
 Query OK, 11320619 rows affected (5 min 53.82 sec)
 Records: 11320619  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

Now, I would like to select distinct rows from the "**holdup table**", delete all the rows in **similarSequence table** and then insert the rows from the **holdup table**. I am not sure how to proceed further as this is my first time with mysql.

Comment: You pretty much said the answer in your question. [Delete](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/1487/delete#t=201608161658093478564), then [insert](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/mysql/866/insert/14413/insert-select#t=20160816165714359042).

Comment: Yes, I realized that I can use delete from similarSequences; but after that I was not sure how to insert rows form holdup table to similarsequences table

Comment: Did you take a look at the insert link I used? It takes you directly to an `insert into table_a select ... from table_b`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to get at.

SELECT DISTINCT (rows) FROM holdup

DELETE (rows)

INSERT (rows) FROM holdup